# thermodynamic equilibrium under self-gravitation

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, equilibrium, gas

Suppose you have a point mass M in space that is surrounded by a gas of particles mass m at temperature T. Let the gas distribution be spherically symmetric about M. What is the radial dependence of the equilibrium gas distribution? Wish to include the case were M=0.

This may be a trick question because I think the gas may evaporate over time and slowly cool. If this is so, then I want the answer to the question above for short time periods over which the evaporation is negligible.

Many thanks!

Comment: I think that you are more likely to get good answers (and/or just some basic feedback) if you make the effort to solve the problem yourself (which I guess you did) and include your thoughts and doubts... Right now, your post is just "solve this for me".

Comment: [How can I improve my chance of an answer?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9327/how-can-i-improve-the-chances-of-my-question-being-answered)

Comment: I see that some people have put a hold on my question because they think it is a homework problem. I'm a PhD physicist with 25 years working experience and have spent a fair amount of that time as a physics professor. If it sounds like a homework problem, that is because I know how to write specific questions.  Yes, I have considered the problem myself and didn't immediately discern an answer. Yes, perhaps asking stackexchange was a little lazy on my part, but the perception of me trying to cheat on my homework is insulting in the absence of evidence.

Comment: Yes, I have considered the problem myself and didn't immediately discern an answer. Yes, perhaps asking stackexchange was a little lazy on my part, but this isn't my area of expertise and I was hoping to get on with my research. Although I appreciate the answers below, I was hoping for a reference to a text where  I can (re)learn the underlying physics.  I guess stackexchange isn't a resource for active researchers? But rather a tool designed to help students only? I would have thought otherwise.

Comment: I consulted a friend who knows about this stuff and he pointed me to the Lane-Emden equation as a general solution for gases depending on their internal degrees of freedom. There is a Wikipedia page on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take an infinitesimal volume from a sphere with radius r and center at M, we can get the infinitesimal mass. $$dm = \rho \frac43 \pi r^2dr $$

Integrate this, we will get the mass. $$\int_0^\infty dm = m$$

The force between the sheer of mass and the M can be calculated by the following. $$dF=G \frac{Mdm}{r^2}$$

Therefore the total force on the sphere will be the integral below. $$F=\int_r^\infty dF$$

The pressure can therefore be calculated. $$P=\frac{F}{\frac43 \pi r^2}$$

At the same time, using ideal gas state of equation: $$P=\rho RT$$.

Now, I stop here. After you fix it, I will make the rest up.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the equation of hydrostatic equilibrium

$$
\frac{dp}{dr} = \frac{kT}{m}\frac{d\rho}{dr} = -\frac{d\Phi}{dr}
$$

where $T$ is the temperature, $k$ is Boltzmann's constant, $\rho$ is the density and $\Phi$ the gravitational potential (it depends on $M$). You can rearrange this equation to get

$$
\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\frac{d\ln\rho}{dr} \right) = -\frac{4\pi G m}{kT}r^2\rho
$$

And from here you can solve for the density profile $\rho$

Comment: This is very helpful. Can you direct me to a reference for the first equation? I'm not an astronomer (I work in condensed matter) so I haven't studied this kind of problem before. Thank you.

Comment: @GerryHarp You could try with Galactic Dynamics - Binney & Tremaine 2nd Ed. Sec 4.3

Answer (score 1):

Although detailed answers for the specific case of gas of state equation $P = \rho k_B T/m$ was given, I'll try to give a short but generic answer.

The problem can be divided into two sub-problems :

1. Finding the equation describing the equilibrium between the gravitational force (which depends on $\rho$ via the mass) and the pressure $P$
2. Finding the state equation of the considered gas, which relates $\rho$ and $P$.

The 1st problem leads to either the Newtonian hydrostatic equilibrium equation, or the Tolman–Oppenheimer–Volkoff equation in the relativistic case.

The 2nd problem depends on the physics, for stars the state equation is usually "polytropic".